# Is there a way for modifying molecule in RDkit?

Tags: chemistry, rdkit

I have a branched molecule just like in the Image (left one).

I want to add COOH at the end of each branch like Image (right one)

[image]

Here is the SMILES format of my molecule in a simplified form with 4 branches.

```
[N:1]([CH2:2][CH2:3][N:4]([CH2:47][CH2:48][CH:49]([NH:50][CH2:51][CH2:52][NH2:53])[O-:55])[CH2:66][CH2:67][CH:68]([NH:69][CH2:70][CH2:71][NH2:72])[O-:74])([CH2:9][CH2:10][CH:11]([NH:12][CH2:13][CH2:14][NH2:15])[O-:17])[CH2:28][CH2:29][CH:30]([NH:31][CH2:32][CH2:33][NH2:34])[O-:36]
```

I actually have a much bigger molecule but if i can find a way to do it with the simple one, i think i can extend the solution to the bigger one.

Here is a code example

```
mod_mol = Chem.ReplaceSubstructs(m, 
                                 Chem.MolFromSmiles('[NH2:34]'), 
                                 Chem.MolFromSmiles('[CH2:99]'),
                                 replaceAll=True)
mod_mol[0]
```

for example i tried to change NH2 to CH2 but nothing happens.

Comment: In the post SMILES format doesnt pasted correctly. Here it is 

[N:1]([CH2:2][CH2:3][N:4]([CH2:47][CH2:48][CH:49]([NH:50][CH2:51][CH2:52][NH2:53])[O-:55])[CH2:66][CH2:67][CH:68]([NH:69][CH2:70][CH2:71][NH2:72])[O-:74])([CH2:9][CH2:10][CH:11]([NH:12][CH2:13][CH2:14][NH2:15])[O-:17])[CH2:28][CH2:29][CH:30]([NH:31][CH2:32][CH2:33][NH2:34])[O-:36]

Comment: Please add information to your question by hitting the `edit` button, don't post corrections/additions to your question in the comments

Comment: Have you tried `Chem.ReplaceSubstructs()`?

Comment: i tried afrer your advice but i get an error.

ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    rdkit.Chem.rdmolops.ReplaceSubstructs(Mol, NoneType, Mol)
did not match C++ signature:

Comment: @AykutElmas Seems to be the SMARTS you use. Could you please put a sample code in your question. For me `ReplaceSubstructs` works.

Comment: @raplepy sorry for the late answer. I edited my question as you wish. And added a code example. I hope it helps. I am really stuck.

Comment: @AykutElmas The part to be replaced must be a SMARTS `Chem.MolFromSmarts('[NH2:34]')`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I solved the problem.

Comment: @rapelpy Hey friend. You look like somebody know about rdkit. I have another question about rdkit but no one answered it. Can i ask you?

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is helpful to observe where the error shows a Nonetype. In this case,

```
rdkit.Chem.rdmolops.ReplaceSubstructs(Mol, NoneType, Mol)
```

The issue was caused because `Chem.MolFromSmiles` was provided with a SMARTS string, like this:

```
`Chem.MolFromSmiles('[NH2:34]')`
```

The solution is to use a `Chem.MolFromSmarts` instead, like this:

```
Chem.MolFromSmarts('[NH2:34]')
```